# Using MSAL for Auth/Authz in a Dynamics 365 resource to access external Azure API

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics

I have an Angular application that is deployed as a Web Resource in D365 using MSAL library for Auth/Auhtz to access an external Web API hosted in Azure. When running the app outside Dynamics all works fine, the MSAL library retrieves the acccess token and attaches it to the request for Authorization to the Azure Web API. The problem occurs when I deploy the files as web resources to Dynamics. See below is the error and MSAL config in my app module.

*MSAL Logging:  Fri, 16 Oct 2020 13:14:53 GMT:943d26e4-f4b2-48b7-a882-f1a835959476-1.4.0-Error Error when acquiring token for scopes: https://...azurewebsites.net/default ClientAuthError: User login is required. For silent calls, request must contain either sid or login_hint*

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: config.auth.clientId,
        authority: config.auth.authority,
        redirectUri: config.auth.redirectUri
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: <CacheLocation>config.cache.cacheLocation,
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
      },
    },
      {
        popUp: !isIE,
        consentScopes: config.scopes.graphScopes,
        unprotectedResources: [],
        protectedResourceMap: [
          [config.baseuri, [config.baseuri.concat('/', config.scopes.gatewayScopes)]],
          [config.protectedResources.graphEndpoint, config.scopes.graphScopes]
        ],
        extraQueryParameters: {},        
      })

 providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
]
```

I've been struggling for 2 days now without any luck.

Help Please!!!

Comment: can you send code of app.component.ts with msal service call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following custom interceptor. For this you need to enable the *sid* [optional claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set).

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: MsalService, private broadcastService: BroadcastService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const scopes = this.auth.getScopesForEndpoint(req.url);
    this.auth.getLogger().verbose("Url: " + req.url + " maps to scopes: " + scopes);

    // If there are no scopes set for this request, do nothing.
    if (!scopes) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    let token: string;

    // Acquire a token for this request, and attach as proper auth header.
    const obs = from(
      this.auth.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes, sid: this.auth.getAccount().idTokenClaims["sid"] })
        .then((response: AuthResponse) => {
          token = response.tokenType === ServerHashParamKeys.ID_TOKEN ? response.idToken.rawIdToken : response.accessToken;
          const authHeader = `Bearer ${token}`;
          return req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: authHeader,
            }
          });
        })
    )
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((nextReq: HttpRequest<any>) => next.handle(nextReq)),
        tap(
          event => { }, // tslint:disable-line
          err => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
              this.auth.clearCacheForScope(token);
              this.broadcastService.broadcast("msal:notAuthorized", err.message);
            }
          }
        )
    );

    return obs as Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
    
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting below error now due to this.auth.getACcount() returning null. Any idea why this would happen as I'm already signed into D365.                                                        
                                                                                                                                TypeError: Cannot read property 'idTokenClaims' of null

Comment: Thanks for the help it is much appreciated. To get past the null account I did a null check.                 
                                                                                                                                          let account = this.authService.getAccount();

if (!!account === false) {
      this.login();
}                                                                                                                                     
The onlhy thing I have to figure out now is how to not show the login popup.

Comment: @PatrickLuyt null getAccount can happen when no successful login state is found.

Comment: @PatrickLuyt did you manage to solve the problem? I have quite the same issue

Comment: @Christian Flaviu Yes, enabled/added the Session Id (sid) claim in Azure Portal and added it to the AuthenticationParameters in the auquireTokenSilent() method. See snippet below.

Comment: Note a snippet of the code I added to my Custom Http Interceptor class. let token: string; let tokenRequest = { scopes, sid: 
this.auth.getAccount().idTokenClaims["sid"], loginHint: "preferred_username" };
// Acquire a token for this request, and attach as proper auth header.
const obs = from(
this.auth.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest).then((response: AuthResponse)  => { ... }